# Can't run C/C++ on Mac using VSC or Geany

Tags: c++, c

I tried running a C program and a C++ program on Visual Studio Code (seperately) and when I watch tutorials they show no issues when running, but when I try to run a C++ program it says this: line 7: ./packadd: No such file or directory

If anyone has a solution to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So there is no executable named  `packadd` in the current directory. But I have a feeling that you are using Windows, and on Windows this is not the way of running executables.

Comment: I'm using a macbook air

Comment: There must be something wrong with your compile command.  Can you share how you are compiling your code?  Have you tried compiling an hello world example?  Does it give you the same issue?

Comment: I would start by asking if they even installed a compiler. Either Xcode or the Xcode CLT.